# spark - scala: not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am trying to convert a data frame to RDD, then perform some operations below to return tuples:

```
df.rdd.map { t=>
 (t._2 + "_" + t._3 , t)
}.take(5)
```

Then I got the error below. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

```
<console>:37: error: value _2 is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row
               (t._2 + "_" + t._3 , t)
                  ^
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you convert a DataFrame to RDD, you get an `RDD[Row]`, so when you use `map`, your function receives a `Row` as parameter. Therefore, you must use the `Row` methods to access its members (note that the index starts from 0):

```
df.rdd.map { 
  row: Row => (row.getString(1) + "_" + row.getString(2), row)
}.take(5)
```

You can view more examples and check all methods available for `Row` objects in the [Spark scaladoc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row).

**Edit:** I don't know the reason why you are doing this operation, but for concatenating String columns of a DataFrame you may consider the following option:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val newDF = df.withColumn("concat", concat(df("col2"), lit("_"), df("col3")))
```

Answer (score 9):

You can access every element of a [Row](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row) like if it was a `List` or `Array`, it means using `(index)`, however you can use the method `get` also.

For example:

```scala
df.rdd.map {t =>
  (t(2).toString + "_" + t(3).toString, t)
}.take(5)
```