# How to convert Dataframes from avro to GenericRecord in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am stuck in converting the avro dataframes to GenericRecord/ByteArray where I surfed in google which they provide me solution the other way round.

Have anyone tried converting AVRO RDD/Dataframes to GenericRecord or ByteArray in scala?

I used this command to read my avro files.

```
spark.read.avro("/app/q.avro")
```

It returns me dataframes like this.

```
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [recordType: string, recordVersion: string ... 6 more fields]
```

So How to convert sql.DataFrame to GenericRecord/ByteArray?

Comment: Why do you want to convert Daraframe to other object? I think it should be row to Bytearray not entire dataframe.

Comment: yeah ... Row to ByteArray is also fine for me ...

Answer (score 0):

After creating a dataframe:

```
val df=spark.read.avro("/app/q.avro")
```

You can convert it into either an rdd or a list of strings.

```
val listOfStrings=df.rdd.collect.toList
```

Now, you can convert the list of strings into byteArray, like this:

```
scala> var lst=List("scala","Java","Python","JavaScript")
lst: List[String] = List(scala, Java, Python, JavaScript)

scala> lst.map(_.getBytes).toArray
res5: Array[Array[Byte]] = Array(Array(115, 99, 97, 108, 97), Array(74, 97, 118, 97), Array(80, 121, 116, 104, 111, 110), Array(74, 97, 118, 97, 83, 99, 114, 105, 112, 116))
```

Comment: When I read avro file, df type is "org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame"
df.rdd.toList throws me an error ... " error: value toList is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]"

Comment: listOfStrings: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = MapPartitionsRDD[15] at rdd at <console>:28

Comment: val listOfStrings = df.rdd.collect.toList
listOfStrings: List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]


val r = listOfStrings.getBytes
<console>:30: error: value getBytes is not a member of List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
       val r = listOfStrings.getBytes

Comment: `listOfStrings.map(_.toByte).toArray` try this

Comment: its not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row

Comment: This link should help you, first convert the sql.Row format into strings and run the above comments! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335416/spark-scala-not-a-member-of-org-apache-spark-sql-row

Comment: Seems converting the row would be difficult as the avro here is very complex... can't extract the column easily .. What I've to do is ... convert the whole of each row in to strings and put each row as Strings in List ... is that what u mean ?

Comment: I could able to convert to Strings but not to ByteArray as it throws NumberFormatException

Comment: listOfStrings.map(_.toString).toArray
 r.map(_.toByte).toArray
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:

Comment: My List is not still List[String] .... its List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] where I cannot the Rows to Strings .... it says getBytes is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row